# How do I set my radio button group based on string matching?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

The code snippet below works for inserting a model (_gameFact), but how do I set the correct radio button when recalling from database (in order to edit). The value coming back is a single int (0,1,2,3). This is a work in progress so anything can change if needed to make easier.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><input name="PlayValue" type="radio" @onchange='@(() => _gameFact.PlayValue = 0)' /></div>
    <div class="col"><input name="PlayValue" type="radio" @onchange='@(() => _gameFact.PlayValue = 1)' /></div>
    <div class="col"><input name="PlayValue" type="radio" @onchange='@(() => _gameFact.PlayValue = 2)' /></div>
    <div class="col"><input name="PlayValue" type="radio" @onchange='@(() => _gameFact.PlayValue = 3)' /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can user **checked** for value retrieve from database.

```
    <div class="col"><input name="PlayValue" type="radio" checked="@(_gameFact.PlayValue == 0)" @onchange='@(() => _gameFact.PlayValue = 0)' /></div>
    <div class="col"><input name="PlayValue" type="radio" checked='@(_gameFact.PlayValue == 1)' @onchange='@(() => _gameFact.PlayValue = 1)' /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the build in InputRadioGroup,a minimal Example:

```
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="gameFact.PlayValue" Name="PlayValue" >
    @foreach(var option in Options)
    {
        @option
            <InputRadio Value="option"  />
        <br />
    }
 </InputRadioGroup>
 <div>
     Selected:@gameFact.PlayValue
 </div>
<button @onclick="OnClick">Selct 2</button>


@code{
    

    List<int> Options = new() { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    GameFact gameFact=new();

    private void OnClick()
    {
        //you could create a Enum/Dictionary,map the string to int
        //you could set the value somewhere else such as on OnInitialized method
        gameFact.PlayValue = 2;
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the `InputRadio` with `InputRadioGroup`. Bind the value the group.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Player Race</legend>
    <InputRadioGroup Name="playerRace" @bind-Value="value">
        @foreach (var playerRace in PlayerRaces)
        {
            <label>@playerRace.Name</label>
            <InputRadio Value=playerRace.Id  />
        }
    </InputRadioGroup>
</fieldset>
<hr />
Value: @value
@code {
    private int value;
    private List<PlayerRace> PlayerRaces = [
        new(1, "Dwarf"),
        new(2, "Elf"),
        new(3, "Dark Elf"),
        new(4, "Drop Bear"),
        new(5, "Human")];

    public record PlayerRace(int Id, string Name);

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1500); // simulate api read delay
        value = Random.Shared.Next(1, 6);
    }
}
```